# Local IP in Blackberry Simulator and Windows Phone Simulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, blackberry-simulator

I want to access my data using local network. I have successful in Android Simulator using 10.0.2.2 local IP, but it's didn't work on Windows Phone Simulator and Blackberry Simulator. anyone know what the BB and WP local IP Simulator ?

Answer (score 0):

Which emulator are you using? Windows Phone 7 or Windows Phone 8?
If the former, you should be able to access `localhost`. If the latter, then it might be problematic to configure the localhost connection. The thing is that `localhost` is inside the emulator itself because Windows Phone 8 emulators are Hyper-V machines.

To access via the local IP, you need to configure IIS to map the websites to your IP address. I am sure you'll be able to find the exact solution on the web.

Try these:

- [Troubleshooting the Windows Phone 8 Emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681694%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
- [How to connect to a local web service from the Windows Phone 8 emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: i am using Windows Phone 7. How ?

Comment: Can you confirm that you can access `localhost`? I presume that you do have IIS set up and running.